# web page memory usage in firefox

Tags: firefox, memory, html

Is there any way to know how much memory current web page is using in Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) plugin !

Answer (score 1):

Try the Net tab on Firebug (Firefox Extension). You can see each individual file and its size.

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem of definition in this question, which is common to many questions about "how much memory".

Suppose I have only your page open. Arguably then, all the memory consumed by the browser is for your page, since if I wasn't looking at that I could close the browser and free up all the memory it uses.

On the other hand, consider if I have a dozen similar pages (e.g. pages from the same part of the same site but just with slightly different content) open in tabs. In this case there's a lot of data which the browser could share (and all the popular ones do) between the pages - such as image files, external javascript and CSS, thus reducing the per-page memory usage.

So any certain answer will be predicated on a lot of assumptions.